# How to fix shading on arbitrary JavaFX TriangleMeshes?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-3d

So I love JavaFX for its 2d functionality, and was excited to try the 2d features. Unfortunately, in trying to load arbitrary triangle meshes, I keep getting results like this:

[image]

Is this just the reality of the JavaFX shading algorithm? Or is my model import function just incorrectly written? I have tried tinkering with smoothing groups, vertex normals, and face culling to no avail, and am about ready to give up on JavaFX and Java altogether for this project.

Comment: Could you post which model importer are you using? Importers usually have some limitations regarding the number of faces that can be added to a single element, if you are going to use a `TriangleMesh`. But there are other options...